# Multiple SQL-views, single point of definition, how to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I have the following situation:

- Several database views (around 12, will increase in the future)
- Between 40~100 columns for each view (will also change with each patch)
- Base views that are reused in the other views

The base views are created to make a single point of definition for columns that are shared by the other views. This works great if calculated columns change value, but does not work if columns are removed or added. 
Since I cannot use `SELECT * FROM` because sometimes views are used twice (think of a sender user and a receiver user for a message view).

This situation is slowing turning into a maintenance nightmare since when 1 of the base views change all the other views must also be changed and in practice, some are forgotten.

Is there a way to automatically add columns to all depended views when I add a column to a base view? It would be great if I could prefix columns with the alias I give to a view, but I can't. How to make this maintainable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn on [`SCHEMABINDING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) on all of your views. This won't make anything "automatic" but it will at least prevent you from forgetting to update anything:

```
create table dbo.T1 (ID int not null)
go
create view dbo.V1
with schemabinding
as
    select ID from dbo.T1
go
create view dbo.V2
with schemabinding
as
    select ID from dbo.V1
go
alter view dbo.V1
with schemabinding
as
    select ID,ID+1 as ID2 from dbo.T1
```

Produces:

```
Msg 3729, Level 16, State 3, Procedure V1, Line 1
Cannot ALTER 'dbo.V1' because it is being referenced by object 'V2'.
```

I'm not able to alter `V1` until I (temporarily) remove `V2` (and any other views that depend on it). It also means that dependency tracking meta-data is stored, which can be used to find dependencies beforehand:

```
select distinct OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
from sys.sql_dependencies
where OBJECT_NAME(referenced_major_id) = 'V1'
```

Produces:

```
V2
```

Comment: This will annoy programmers but at least it will prevent errors. +1 but won't mark it as accepted yet, perhaps someone has another idea. Dependencies could also be found with `OBJECT_DEFINITION`. But it still requires the person editing the views to know about it and use it.